# An apparent contradiction to $m = m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, mass-energy, inertia

Using theoretical framework of the special relativity, we can show that the quantity that we classically regard as energy does have a property of inertia. And particularly, if the total energy of a box is $L$ then its inertia is $L/c^2$. Now suppose I have an infinitely large parallel plate capacitor which is at rest in an inertial frame $O$. Uniformly charged plates of the capacitors have such a charge density so that the uniform electric field between the plates is $E$.

Now in a frame of reference $O'$ which is moving uniformly along the area vector of the plate plane with respect to $O$, the electric field will be $E$ and magnetic field would still remain zero.

In $O$ frame, the total energy of capacitor is $L_1 = l_0 \int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2 dA $ and thus its mass is $m_1 = L_1/c^2$.Where $l_0$ is the perpendicular separation between the plates and $dA$ is the infinitesimal small area element of one of the plates in $O$ frame.

In $O'$ frame, the total energy of the capacitor is $L_2 = l_0\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} \int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2 dA $ . The infinitesimal $dA$ and limits of integration remain exactly the same because no length contraction happen in the direction perpendicular to the relative motion. Here also the mass is thus $m_2 = L_2/c^2$.

So, $m_2$ = $m_1$ $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. But in general, in relativity we prove that $m = m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. So why does this apparent contradiction is happening? Does it have to do anything with the fact that actually both the $m_1$ and $m_2$ are infinities? Because I doubt that it might be the case that we cannot directly write  $m_2$ = $m_1$ $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ because $m_2$ and $m_1$ are infinities. But on the other hand that relation seems to hold pretty well from their corresponding expressions in the integral form.

Comment: Treating $m[1 - \beta^2]^{-1/2}$ as inertia has problems from the very beginning. It is the correct inertia for forces acting transverse to the direction of relative motion, but is not correct for longitudinal forces.

Comment: @dmckee But while proving the $m = m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ relation, we analyse a collision which has longitudinal forces. Can you suggest the reason why the expression shouldn't hold for some cases?

Comment: @dmckee Can you provide some link where I can read the relevant literature on the problems with $m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ expression?

Comment: mass is velocity-independent. $m=\gamma m_0$ is a historical mistake, and shouldnt be taken seriously in any context.

Comment: @qftishard I know in recent literature we consider rest mass to be the mass. And rest mass is obviously velocity independent. But are you suggesting that the inertia of a body doesn't change with the speed? I think then it creates a lot of problems with momentum conservation in the relativistic context. Can you provide some web link to read about what you are suggesting?

Comment: I recommend that you: 1: Accept those results. 2: Understand those results by considering the energy needed to accelerate a plate capacitor when A: plate distance length contracts B: plate distance does not change.

Answer (score 1):

> Using theoretical framework of the special relativity, we can show that the quantity that we classically regard as energy does have a property of inertia.

It's isn't as straightforward as having a scalar $m$ like in $\vec F=m\vec a.$ And if you have mechanical momentum like $\vec p=\vec vE/c^2$ then mass doesn't appear at all and $d\vec p/dt$ has to definitely adjust the energy and maybe the velocity or the speed too. But since the energy depends on the full 3d motion you don't get the simple separation of changes in velocity components for each of the three components like you do in Newtonian mechanics. But you can get a nice change in momentum.

No word games can change that momentum can steadily increase while energy and/or velocity can be a more complicated change.

> And particularly, if the total energy of a box is $L$ then its inertia is $L/c^2$.

That's a pretty big claim. If it weren't so vague I'd say its provably wrong.

> In $O$ frame, the total energy of capacitor is $L_1 = l_0 \int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2 dA $ and thus its mass is $m_1 = L_1/c^2$.

That's not true. A capacitor has massive plates and charges and such and some stress holding all the charges together and so there is more energy than the fields, and there is stress so there is more than just energy.

> In $O'$ frame, the total energy of the capacitor is $L_2 = l_0\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} \int\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2 dA $ .

Now there is kinetic energy of the massive charges too, and the stress is involved as well.

> Here also the mass is thus $m_2 = L_2/c^2$.

No. Mass isn't just energy divided by $c^2$ you need the total energy (not just some of it) and you need the momentum (and in this frame there is momentum for the charges).

> But in general, in relativity we prove that $m = m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$.

That's not true either. Sure if the total energy momentum vector exists and is timelike then there is a center of momentum frame and in that frame there is an energy and if you divide that by $c^2$ you can call that the rest mass of the system. And then you can compare the total energy in other frames to that energy and it will be larger in the other frames.

But the spatial integral of the field energy is not the total energy and it isn't the time component of the total energy momentum of a system. And a good way you can tell physically is ...

**There is no rest frame or center of momentum frame for a bare electric field with no charges.**

So clearly the field energy isn't a tine component of a timelike vector. Which you can tell by the fact that there isn't a fixed frame where it is smaller than any other frame.

> So why does this apparent contradiction is happening?

There is no contradiction. The energy of a bare electric field simply doesn't transform the way you claimed it does. No one said it did.

Were you expecting field energy to have a mass all by itself?

You did **completely** ignore whatever force is keeping those charged plates from slamming into each other (you ignored it in both frames), and that force has some energy too.

> Does it have to do anything with the fact that actually both the $m_1$ and $m_2$ are infinities?

No. You could talk about finite sized capacitors. Or even do a calculation in a finite universe, such as a universe that is infinite in z the direction but if you go in the x or y directions it repeats Pac Man style.

The key is to avoid the bad physics. And just like two frames can disagree about which objects have kinetic energy, you must include absolutely every bit of energy, the stress of the plates and wires, the energy of the fields, the kinetic energy and rest energy of the parts of the plates, everything.

Comment: Special relativity suggests that mass indicates the energy content of the body. The 'useful' mass is rest mass which is by definition invariant. But still there exists a quantity called relativistic mass which is not a lorentz scalar. Also, if relativistic mass of a body is $m$ then it essentially means that the total energy of the body is $mc^2$. Total energy of a body transforms as $E = E_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ and so does the relativistic mass.

Comment: @Dvij Be intellectually honest. Don't pretend that using two words (energy and relativistic mass) for the same thing is an accomplishment or any kind of insight. Call it energy and move on with your life. Special relativity didn't "indicate" that you should make up two words for the same thing and call it an accomplishment. You say there is a thing called relativistic mass and I say there is a thing called energy. But the point is you can't just take equations and replace mass with energy and expect it to now be correct, that's wrong. Momentum conservation works if you use correct equations.

Comment: @Dvij Just a bit of advice: If you consider a system of two objects, and increase that system's rest mass by accelerating the two objects to opposite directions, then you are effectively using relativistic mass but nobody can complain! ;)

Comment: @user7027 In the specific question the OP asked, we can and do complain. Ignoring some of the stress or momentum or energy does give wrong answers. Just as two objects with relative  velocity can have different parts have kinetic energy depending on frame so can different energies of different parts be important to the total energy of a system. The OP is definitely making mistakes and playing semantic games won't fix it, the OP needs to actually learn relativity and track **all** the energy, stress, and momentum instead of picking and choosing.

Comment: I am not telling total energy of the entire "capacitor+assembly holding capacitor plates" to be the integration of $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2$. But I am particularly choosing the system consisting of only the fields between the plates.

Comment: @Dvij Field energy alone is neither conserved in time, nor frame invariant, and also doesn't transform between frames according to your equation. Total energy isn't frame invariant but it is conserved and does transform correctly. Now I'm beginning to think you don't even have a question and just like to use random equations for random reasons. What contradiction? Your baseless assumptions that you can consider some energy and ignore all the momentum and all the stress and expect it to have any meaning whatsoever. OK. You showed that baseless assumption is wrong. Great. How is this an issue ?

Comment: The system comprising of the space between the plates has total energy (NOT the  total energy of the entire "capacitor+assembly holding capacitor plates" ) equals to the field energy, because there is nothing else. And then why should the energy of this system shouldn't transform the way energy in general transforms between the frames?

Comment: @Dvij Firstly it doesn't. Secondly there is no reason it should. The fields transform as part of a larger system that also has charges and stresses and momentum as well as field energy. If using the word mass made you think you could take any part of a total energy and then ignore other energy and ignore stress and ignore momentum and that this wouldn't bite you. Then using that word has mislead you. In relativity there is a stress energy tensor, it's real, and it includes all the energy, all the momentum, and all the stress and does so in way where it transforms correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what part of total energy I have ignored if my system is just the space between the plates.

Comment: @Dvij You don't get to make up any thing you feel like and call it a system and expect it to transform correctly. No one ever told you that you could. And you can't. Plus you'd still need the stress and the momentum even if you did because this is an extended system and those are the other relativistic parts of energy **density**.

Comment: @Dvij I edited the answer to try to be more clear.

Comment: @Timaeus A positron and an electron are 10000 km apart. A suitable boost brings those particles arbitrarily close to each other, which makes the energy of the pair arbitrarily low, where the meaning of energy is such that that energy becomes low. I don't know if we agree about energy becoming low, but as I just got rid of all the unnecessary things, we might start to answering the question of energy becoming low or not becoming low.

Comment: @user7027 If you use standard special relativity, standard classical electromagnetism, and point charges then the field energy is infinite in any frame. If you replace the point charges with continuous charge distributions then the energy of the field doesn't transform as component of a total energy momentum four vector. But if you include the Poincaré stress holding the continuous charge distribution together and include all the energy, all the momentum, and all the stress. Then it all works out. You really do need the stress and all the energy and momentum to make it work.